# deselect already selected node in Treeview while pressing Ctrl+click

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I am having problem with deselecting already selected node in Treeview while pressing Ctrl+click. Even no event is triggered while pressing Ctrl+click to already selected node.
So I wanted to deselect already selected node in Treeview pressing Ctrl+click.

Regards.

Comment: Why not just `Click` wihout `Ctrl`? The combination of `Ctrl + Click` is used for selecting multi-items.

Comment: Hi, King King thanks for response. well, is it possible to deselect the already selected node pressing just click or Ctrl+click in Treeview like Windows standard behavior?

Comment: Hey, normally clicking will make the previous selected nodes become `deselected`, the clicked node will become the only selected one. Why do you find a thing which is supported by default? BTW, I've tried it and even `Ctrl + Click` can't select multi-nodes in a `TreeView`. What kind of `TreeView` are you using?

Comment: well, I added treeview control in my windows Form and having problem with deselecting previously selected Node by pressing just click or Ctrl+click.

Comment: BTW, it's still unclear on this, you say `click or Ctrl + click` but click on what? I think the answer given below is OK.

Answer (score 1):

you can use 
TreeView1.Items[i].Selected = false;